# How can I use the StringEscapeUtils Class to secure the code from LDAP injection vulnerabilities?

Tags: java, security, ldap, code-injection

How can I use the `StringEscapeUtils` Class to secure the code  from LDAP injection vulnerabilities?
How do I escape `searchBase`, `searchMask`, `scontrols`?

```
try {
do {


NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = null;
try {
   answer = ctx.search(searchBase, searchMask, scontrols);
   printSearchEnumeration(answer);
   if (maxSize == 0)
     exceedLimit = false;
   else {
     if (list.size() >= maxSize)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) as this only `Escapes and unescapes Strings for Java, Java Script, HTML and XML.`

You should use a positive validation scheme to ensure that the LDAP query only contains "safe" characters. In some cases you will be able to escape special characters, but this is not consistent like it is with HTML and Javascript escaping. Check out [OWASP's Preventing LDAP Injection in Java](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_LDAP_Injection_in_Java).